# JUNIT NOT USING src/test/resources while running the test case in quarkus

Tags: java, quarkus

I have specified the storage dir in `application.properties` file.

```
%test.storage.dir=src/test/resources
```

But while running the test case it is not accessing the files in resource folder.

I have the same path specified for development also and getting response for the API using postman. BUt the test case for the API call is not using the resources.

Comment: Can you show the code here? BTW, why do you have % in front of "test.storage.dir" @vaishali?

Comment: Your test code should be using src/test/resources without having to specify it in any property.

Comment: `src/test/resources` is the classpath so that isn't avaijlable as a location when running the test (as it is the root of the classpath for testing).